# Surgery diagrams of 3-dim abstract open books

Tags: differential-topology, 3-manifolds, 4-manifolds

Starting with an abstract open book $(\Sigma,\phi)$, I would like to understand some of the manifolds that I could obtain. Given a surface $\Sigma$ and monodromy $\phi$, it is not hard to find a Kirby diagram for the Lefschetz fibration that it bounds. However, once I have a found such a diagram, I would like to be able to recognize its boundary as a `familiar' 3-manifold, or a class of manifolds that people care about, like Seifert fibered spaces, or Breiskorn spheres for example. Are there any good examples?

Thankyou in advance for any sort of help!

Comment: To be clear: is your question "I have a surgery presentation of a 3-manifold, how can I identify the manifold?"?

Comment: Yes, how can I identify the manifold other than just saying it is an abstract open book.

Comment: To me, this is still more art than science. You play around with Kirby moves and you see whether you can "simplify" the surgery presentation. If you get the surgery diagram corresponding to a star-shaped plumbing, then you get yourself a SFS. If you want to identify the manifold, the quickest option is probably SnapPy (http://www.math.uic.edu/~t3m/SnapPy/).